# Ebay past prices

Tags: ebay

Is there a method to view the prices an item sold for in the past?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [search for completed listings](http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/buy/questions/search-completed-listings.html) which will show you the kind of prices similar items have been going for.

Comment: This seems to look back max. 90 days. Is there a way to go further back?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do some more complex analysis, there are companies like [this one](https://www.terapeak.com/) or [eBay's developer program](http://developer.ebay.com/products/research/) that will let you get at data in a more easily analyzable form than the completed listings search.